# customizing completion of GtkComboBoxText

Tags: c, linux, gtk, gtk3

How can I customize the completion of a [`GtkComboBoxText`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkComboBoxText.html) with both a "static" aspect and a "dynamic" one? The static aspect is because some entries are known and added to the combo-box-text at construction time with `gtk_combo_box_text_append_text`. The dynamic aspect is because I also need to complete thru some callback function(s), that is to complete *dynamically* -after creation of the `GtkComboBoxText` widget- once several characters has been typed.

My application uses Boehm's GC (except for GTK objects of course) like Guile or SCM or Bigloo are doing. It can be seen as an experimental *persistent* dynamic-typed programming language implementation with an integrated editor coded on and for Debian/Linux/x86-64 with the system GTK3.21 library, it is coded in C99 (some of which is generated) and is compiled with GCC6.

<sup>(I don't care about non-Linux systems, GTK3 libraries older than GTK3.20, GCC compiler older that GCC6)</sup>

#### question details

I'm entering (inputting into the `GtkComboBoxText`) either a *name*, or an *object-id*.

- The *name* is C-identifier-like but starts with a letter and cannot end with an underscore. For example, `comment`, `if`, `the_GUI`, `the_system`, `payload_json`, or `x1` are valid names (but <strike>`_a0bcd`</strike> or <strike>`foobar_`</strike> are invalid names, because they start or end with an underscore). I currently have a big dozen of names, but I could have a few thousands of them. So it would be reasonable to offer a completion once only a single or perhaps two letters has been typed, and completion for names can happen statically because they are not many of them (so I feel reasonable to call `gtk_combo_box_append_text` for each name).
- The *object-id* starts with an underscore followed by a digit and has exactly 18 alphanumeric (sort-of random) characters. For example, `_5Hf0fFKvRVa71ZPM0`, `_8261sbF1f9ohzu2Iu`, `_0BV96V94PJIn9si1K` are possible object-ids. Actually it is 96 almost random bits (probably only 2<sup>94</sup> are possible). The object-id plays the role of [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)s (in the sense that it is assumed to be world-wide unique for distinct objects) but has a C friendly syntax. I currently have a few dozen of objects-ids, but I could have a few hundred of thousands (or maybe a million) of them. But given a prefix of four characters like `_6S3` or `_22z`, I am assuming that only a reasonable number (probably at most a dozen, and surely no more than a thousand) *object-ids* exist in my application with that prefix. Of course it would be unreasonable to register (statically) *a priori* all the object ids (the completion has to happen after four characters have been typed, and should happen dynamically).

So I want a completion that works both on names (e.g. typing one letter perhaps followed by another alphanum character should be enough to propose a completion of at most a hundred choices), and on object-ids (typing four characters like `_826` should be enough to trigger a completion of probably at most a few dozen choices, perhaps a thousand ones if unlucky).

Hence typing the three keys <kbd>p</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>tab</kbd> would offer completion with a few names like `payload_json` or `payload_vectval` etc... and typing the five keys <kbd>_</kbd> <kbd>5</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd> <kbd>tab</kbd> would offer completion with very few object-ids, notably `_5Hf0fFKvRVa71ZPM0`

#### sample *incomplete* code

So far I coded the following:

```
static GtkWidget *
mom_objectentry (void)
{
  GtkWidget *obent = gtk_combo_box_text_new_with_entry ();
  gtk_widget_set_size_request (obent, 30, 10);
  mo_value_t namsetv = mo_named_objects_set ();
```

I have Boehm-garbage-collected values, and `mo_value_t` is a pointer to any of them. Values can be tagged integers, pointers to strings, objects, or tuples or sets of objects. So `namesetv` now contains the set of named objects (probably less than a few thousand of named objects).

```
  int nbnam = mo_set_size (namsetv);
  MOM_ASSERTPRINTF (nbnam > 0, "bad nbnam");
  mo_value_t *namarr = mom_gc_alloc (nbnam * sizeof (mo_value_t));
  int cntnam = 0;
  for (int ix = 0; ix < nbnam; ix++)
    {
      mo_objref_t curobr = mo_set_nth (namsetv, ix);
      mo_value_t curnamv = mo_objref_namev (curobr);
      if (mo_dyncast_string (curnamv))
        namarr[cntnam++] = curnamv;
    }
  qsort (namarr, cntnam, sizeof (mo_value_t), mom_obname_cmp);
  for (int ix = 0; ix < cntnam; ix++)
    gtk_combo_box_text_append_text (GTK_COMBO_BOX_TEXT (obent),
                    mo_string_cstr (namarr[ix]));
```

at this point I have sorted all the (few thousands at most)  names and added "statically" them using `gtk_combo_box_text_append_text`.

```
  GtkWidget *combtextent = gtk_bin_get_child (GTK_BIN (obent));
  MOM_ASSERTPRINTF (GTK_IS_ENTRY (combtextent), "bad combtextent");
  MOM_ASSERTPRINTF (gtk_entry_get_completion (GTK_ENTRY (combtextent)) ==
                    NULL, "got completion in combtextent");
```

I noticed with a bit of surprise that `gtk_entry_get_completion (GTK_ENTRY (combtextent))` is null.

But I am stuck here. I am thinking of:

1. Having some `mom_set_complete_objectid(const char*prefix)` which given a `prefix` like `"_47n"` of at least four characters would return a garbage collected `mo_value_t` representing the set of objects with that prefix. This is very easy to code for me, and is nearly done.
2. Make my own local `GtkEntryCompletion* mycompl =` ..., which would complete like I want. Then I would put it in the text entry `combtextent` of my *gtk-combo-box-text* using `gtk_entry_set_completion(GTK_ENTRY(combtextent), mycompl);`

Should it use the entries added with `gtk_combo_box_text_append_text` for the "static" name completion role? How should I dynamically complete using the dynamic set value returned from my `mom_set_complete_objectid`; given some object-pointer `obr` and some `char bufid[20];` I am easily and quickly able to fill it with the object-id of that object `obr` with `mo_cstring_from_hi_lo_ids(bufid, obr->mo_ob_hid, obr->mo_ob_loid)`..

I don't know how to code the above. For reference, I am now just returning the combo-box-text:

```
  // if the entered text starts with a letter, I want it to be
  // completed with the appended text above if the entered text starts
  // with an undersore, then a digit, then two alphanum (like _0BV or
  // _6S3 for example), I want to call a completion function.
#warning objectentry: what should I code here?
  return obent;
}  /* end mom_objectentry */
```

Is my approach the right one?

The `mom_objectentry` function above is used to fill modal dialogs with short lifetime.

I am favoring simple code over efficiency. Actually, my code is temporary (I'm hoping to bootstrap my language, and generate all its C code!) and in practice I'll probably have only a few hundred names and at most a few dozen of thousands of object-ids. So performance is not very important, but simplicity of coding (some conceptually "throw away" code) is more important.

I don't want (if possible) to add my own GTK classes. I prefer using existing GTK classes and widgets, customizing them with GTK signals and callbacks.

#### context

My application is an experimental [**persistent**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_%28computer_science%29) programming language and implementation with a near Scheme or Python (or JavaScript, ignoring the prototype aspect, ...) *semantics* but with a widely different (not yet implemented in september 7<sup>th</sup>, 2016) syntax (to be shown & input in GTK widgets), using the Boehm garbage collector for values (including objects, sets, tuples, strings...)... Values (including objects) are generally persistent (except the GTK related data : the application starts with a nearly empty window). The entire language heap is persisted in JSON-like syntax in some Sqlite "database" (generated at application exit) dumped into [`_momstate.sql`](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor-2015/blob/e2b3b99ef663947201df7b389a02230c6b82dcf6/_momstate.sql) which is re-loaded at application startup. Object-ids are useful to show object references to the user in GTK widgets, for persistence, and to generate C code related to the objects (e.g. the object of id `_76f7e2VcL8IJC1hq6` could be related to a `mo_76f7e2VcL8IJC1hq6` identifier in some generated C code; this is partly why I have my object-id format instead of using UUIDs).

PS. My C code is GPLv3 free software and available on github. It is the MELT monitor, branch [expjs](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor-2015/tree/expjs), commit [e2b3b99ef66394...](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor-2015/commit/e2b3b99ef663947201df7b389a02230c6b82dcf6)

<sup>NB: The objects mentioned here are implicitly my language objects, not GTK objects. The all have a unique object-id, and some but not most of them are named.</sup>

Comment: Just responding to the bounty, I do have a hunch how to do it but I normally program GTK3 stuff in Python. So is it okay for you to use Pseudocode/python in the answer?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Python, so I would prefer an answer in C. However, I probably would try to adapt a Python based answer -much better than nothing- to C. Notice also that all the GTK [reference documentation](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/) is about C functions of my system's `libgtk-3.so.0`. So perhaps you might name some functions there...

Comment: I've added the way I would approach this as an "answer". The key difference is that I'd use a `GtkListStore` model in the `GtkComboBox` to maintain the list of copies of the matching keywords (letting Gtk+ reference-count and garbage-collect them as it sees fit), with the `popup` signal triggering list regeneration. This seems to work fine for about a thousand matches based on my crude test program (although it could just be the stupid way it creates the `GtkListStore` is the bottleneck).  I do not consider it a *complete* or *real* answer; just my starting point towards a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my suggestion:

Use a [GtkListStore](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkListStore.html) to contain a list of GTK-managed strings (essentially, copies of your identifier string) that match the current prefix string.

(As documented for [`gtk_list_store_set()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkListStore.html#gtk-list-store-set), a `G_TYPE_STRING` item is copied. I consider the overhead of the extra copy acceptable here; it should not affect real-world performance much anyway, I think, and in return, GTK+ will manage the reference counting for us.)

The above is implemented in a GTK+ callback function, which gets an extra pointer as payload (set at the time the GUI is created or activated; I suggest you use some structure to keep references you need to generate the matches). The callback is connected to the combobox `popup` signal, so that it gets called whenever the list is expanded.

Note that as B8vrede noted in a comment, a `GtkComboBoxText` should not be modified via its model; that is why one should/must use a `GtkComboBox` instead.

**Practical example**

For simplicity, let's assume all the data you need to find or generate all known identifiers matched against is held in a structure, say

```
struct generator {
    /* Whatever data you need to generate prefix matches */
};
```

and the combo box populator helper function is then something like

```
static void combo_box_populator(GtkComboBox *combobox, gpointer genptr)
{
    struct generator *const generator = genptr;

    GtkListStore *combo_list = GTK_LIST_STORE(gtk_combo_box_get_model(combobox));

    GtkWidget *entry = gtk_bin_get_child(GTK_BIN(combobox));
    const char *prefix = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry));
    const size_t prefix_len = (prefix) ? strlen(prefix) : 0;

    GtkTreeIter iterator;

    /* Clear the current store */
    gtk_list_store_clear(combo_list);

    /* Initialize the list iterator */
    gtk_tree_model_get_iter_first(GTK_TREE_MODEL(combo_list), &iterator);

    /* Find all you want to have in the combo box;
       for each  const char *match, do:
    */

        gtk_list_store_append(combo_list, &iterator);
        gtk_list_store_set(combo_list, &iterator, 0, match, -1);

    /* Note that the string pointed to by match is copied;
       match is not referred to after the _set() returns.
    */
}
```

When the UI is built or activated, you need to ensure the `GtkComboBox` has an entry (so the user can write text into it), and a `GtkListStore` model:

```
    struct generator *generator;
    GtkWidget *combobox;
    GtkListStore *combo_list;

    combo_list = gtk_list_store_new(1, G_TYPE_STRING);
    combobox = gtk_combo_box_new_with_model_and_entry(GTK_TREE_MODEL(combo_list));
    gtk_combo_box_set_id_column(GTK_COMBO_BOX(combobox), 0);
    gtk_combo_box_set_entry_text_column(GTK_COMBO_BOX(combobox), 0);
    gtk_combo_box_set_button_sensitivity(GTK_COMBO_BOX(combobox), GTK_SENSITIVITY_ON);

    g_signal_connect(combobox, "popup", G_CALLBACK(combo_box_populator), generator);
```

On my system, the default pop-up accelerator is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>, but I assume you've already changed that to <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

I have a crude working example [here](http://www.nominal-animal.net/answers/combo-box-example.tar.xz) (a `.tar.xz` tarball, [CC0](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/)): it reads lines from standard input, and lists the ones matching the user prefix in reverse order in the combo box list (when popped-up). If the entry is empty, the combobox will contain all input lines. I didn't change the default accelerators, so instead of <kbd>Tab</kbd>, try <kbd>Alt+Down</kbd>.

I also have the same example, but using `GtkComboBoxText` instead, [here](http://www.nominal-animal.net/answers/combo-box-text-example.tar.xz) (also [CC0](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/)). This does not use a `GtkListStore` model, but uses [`gtk_combo_box_text_remove_all()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkComboBoxText.html#gtk-combo-box-text-remove-all) and [`gtk_combo_box_text_append_text()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkComboBoxText.html#gtk-combo-box-text-append-text) functions to manipulate the list contents directly. (There is just a few different lines in the two examples.) Unfortunately, the documentation is not explicit whether this interface references or copies the strings. Although copying is the only option that makes sense, and this can be verified from the current Gtk+ sources, the lack of explicit documentation makes me hesitant.

Comparing the two examples I linked to above (both grab some 500 random words from `/usr/share/dict/words` if you compile and run it with `make`), I don't see any speed difference. Both use the same naïve way of picking prefix matches from a linked list, which means the two methods (`GtkComboBox` + model, or `GtkComboBoxText`) should be about equally fast.

On my own machine, both get annoyingly slow with more than 1000 or so matches in the popup; with just a hundred or less matches, it feels instantaneous. This, to me, indicates that the slow/naïve way of picking prefix matches from a linked list is not the culprit (because the entire list is traversed in both cases), but that the GTK+ combo boxes are just not designed for large lists. (The slowdown is definitely much, much worse than linear.)

Comment: Thanks. It is probably the answer I was hoping. I will probably accept in a few hours or days, when I'll code something with it. BTW, is your crude working example available somewhere as free software (e.g. on github)?

Comment: The problem with this code is that it ignores an important comment in the documentation namely: "You should not call `gtk_combo_box_set_model()` or attempt to pack more cells into this combo box via its GtkCellLayout interface." (https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkComboBoxText.html)

Comment: @B8vrede: you are right. But then do you have a constructive suggestion? If yes, please try to write some answer....

Comment: I'm currently writing one, that is how I found the comment ;)

Comment: Basile, @B8vrede: I missed that comment (apologies! -- this is why I always say I make errors; thank you for noting it), ouch. Fortunately, it is actually trivial to fix: just switch to a `GtkComboBox` instead of `GtkComboBoxText`. I shall fix my answer.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I don't use social sites. GitHub is borderline; I will create an account when/if I feel socially functional enough. In any case, I added an explicit CC0 licensing note in the new tarballs (covers both source and the Makefile).

Answer (score 5):

I will not show exact code on how to do it because I never did GTK & C only GTK & Python, but it should be fine as the functions in C and Python functions can easily be translated.

OP's approach is actually the right one, so I will try to fill in the gaps. As the amount of static options is limited probably won't change to much it indeed makes sense to add them using `gtk_combo_box_text_append` which will add them to the internal model of the `GtkComboBoxText`.

Thats covers the static part, for the dynamic part it would be perfect if we could just store this static model and replace it with a temporay model using `gtk_combo_box_set_model()` when a `_` was found at the start of the string. But we shouldn't do this as the documentation says:

> You should not call gtk_combo_box_set_model() or attempt to pack more cells into this combo box via its GtkCellLayout interface.

So we need to work around this, one way of doing this is by adding a `GtkEntryCompletion` to the entry of the `GtkComboBoxText`. This will make the entry attempt to complete the current string based on its current model. As an added bonus it can also add all the character all options have in common like this:

[image]

As we don't want to load all the dynamic options before hand I think the best approach will be to connect a `changed` listener to the `GtkEntry`, this way we can load the dynamic options when we have a underscore and some characters.

As the `GtkEntryCompletion` uses a `GtkListStore` internally, we can **reuse part of the code Nominal Animal provided in his answer**. The main difference being: the `connect` is done on the `GtkEntry` and the replacing of `GtkComboText` with `GtkEntryCompletion` inside the populator. Then everything should be fine, I wish I would be able to write decent C then I would have provided you with code but this will have to do.

**Edit:** A small demo in Python with GTK3

```
import gi

gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')

import gi.repository.Gtk as Gtk

class CompletingComboBoxText(Gtk.ComboBoxText):
    def __init__(self, static_options, populator, **kwargs):
        # Set up the ComboBox with the Entry
        Gtk.ComboBoxText.__init__(self, has_entry=True, **kwargs)

        # Store the populator reference in the object
        self.populator = populator

        # Create the completion
        completion = Gtk.EntryCompletion(inline_completion=True)

        # Specify that we want to use the first col of the model for completion
        completion.set_text_column(0)
        completion.set_minimum_key_length(2)

        # Set the completion model to the combobox model such that we can also autocomplete these options
        self.static_options_model = self.get_model()
        completion.set_model(self.static_options_model)

        # The child of the combobox is the entry if 'has_entry' was set to True
        entry = self.get_child()
        entry.set_completion(completion)

        # Set the active option of the combobox to 0 (which is an empty field)
        self.set_active(0)

        # Fill the model with the static options (could also be used for a history or something)
        for option in static_options:
            self.append_text(option)

        # Connect a listener to adjust the model when the user types something
        entry.connect("changed", self.update_completion, True)


    def update_completion(self, entry, editable):
        # Get the current content of the entry
        text = entry.get_text()

        # Get the completion which needs to be updated
        completion = entry.get_completion()

        if text.startswith("_") and len(text) >= completion.get_minimum_key_length():
            # Fetch the options from the populator for a given text
            completion_options = self.populator(text)

            # Create a temporary model for the completion and fill it
            dynamic_model = Gtk.ListStore.new([str])
            for completion_option in completion_options:
                dynamic_model.append([completion_option])
            completion.set_model(dynamic_model)
        else:
            # Restore the default static options
            completion.set_model(self.static_options_model)


def demo():
    # Create the window
    window = Gtk.Window()

    # Add some static options
    fake_static_options = [
        "comment",
        "if",
        "the_GUI",
        "the_system",
        "payload_json",
        "x1",
        "payload_json",
        "payload_vectval"
    ]

    # Add the the Combobox
    ccb = CompletingComboBoxText(fake_static_options, dynamic_option_populator)
    window.add(ccb)

    # Show it
    window.show_all()
    Gtk.main()


def dynamic_option_populator(text):
    # Some fake returns for the populator
    fake_dynamic_options = [
        "_5Hf0fFKvRVa71ZPM0",
        "_8261sbF1f9ohzu2Iu",
        "_0BV96V94PJIn9si1K",
        "_0BV1sbF1f9ohzu2Iu",
        "_0BV0fFKvRVa71ZPM0",
        "_0Hf0fF4PJIn9si1Ks",
        "_6KvRVa71JIn9si1Kw",
        "_5HKvRVa71Va71ZPM0",
        "_8261sbF1KvRVa71ZP",
        "_0BKvRVa71JIn9si1K",
        "_0BV1KvRVa71ZPu2Iu",
        "_0BV0fKvRVa71ZZPM0",
        "_0Hf0fF4PJIbF1f9oh",
        "_61sbFV0fFKn9si1Kw",
        "_5Hf0fFKvRVa71ozu2",
    ]

    # Only return those that start with the text
    return [fake_dynamic_option for fake_dynamic_option in fake_dynamic_options if fake_dynamic_option.startswith(text)]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    demo()
    Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Other than adding the inline completion (in addition to the popup completion), are there any reasons to use a `GtkEntryCompletion` and `GtkComboBoxText` rather than a `GtkComboBox`? Only `GtkComboBoxText` has the don't-mess-with-the-model restriction.

Comment: Do you have some Python code to share with us? And what exact GTK3 version?

Comment: @NominalAnimal Sorry missed your comment, the advantage is mainly the inline completion. Which for a user experience perspective makes more sense then a combo box. But I guess your answer is closer to OP's request now that you solve the issue with the restriction.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Added a demo with a lot of comments :)

Comment: It probably could be the right answer (because sadly @NominalAnimal's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39420466/841108) and demo leave a blank window on my system).